# How to make apscheduler jobs run when served with WSGI + Apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi, apscheduler

I am working on a flask backend and one of its features require regular calls to an external API and store some results in the database. I used APScheduler to do so.

Not having full access to the upstream server (docker container within google cloud platforms), we managed to serve the backend using apache's mod_wsgi.

Running the backend from my debugger on my PC, the scheduled tasks seem to work as my database is populated.

But the server does not seem to run those tasks at all at when I query the database which should be populated, the tables are empty.

My usage of APScheduler is as follows in the `__init__.py` :

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# Some unrelated code here

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
import module as service
scheduler.add_job(service.job1, 'interval', minutes=10)
scheduler.add_job(service.job2, 'interval', minutes=5)
scheduler.add_job(service.job3, 'interval', minutes=1)
scheduler.start()
```

I'm asking if there are additional steps that I need to do in order for those tasks to be run on the upstream server.

Comment: You do not seem to connect to any database here, so the scheduler starts with a blank slate.

Comment: Also, have you read the [FAQ](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-apscheduler-in-a-web-application)?

Comment: those job1, job2 and job3 are connecting to the database, and the configuration and all are not written here to avoid too much code